# wine: Unhandled page fault When running a windows program

Tags: wine

I installed this program with msiexec and run it with wine appending the resultant file.
It crashed and I got this error in in console

````
0070:err:ole:start_rpcss Failed to start RpcSs service
0070:fixme:imm:ImeSetActiveContext (0000000000010026, 0): stub
0070:fixme:imm:ImmReleaseContext (0000000000010020, 0000000000010026): stub
009c:fixme:imm:ImeSetActiveContext (000000000001005A, 1): stub
009c:fixme:imm:ImmReleaseContext (0000000000020052, 000000000001005A): stub
0094:fixme:dbghelp:elf_search_auxv can't find symbol in module
0094:fixme:dbghelp:elf_search_auxv can't find symbol in module
0094:fixme:dbghelp:elf_search_auxv can't find symbol in module
0094:fixme:dbghelp:elf_search_auxv can't find symbol in module
0094:fixme:dbghelp:elf_search_auxv can't find symbol in module
0094:fixme:dbghelp:elf_search_auxv can't find symbol in module
0094:fixme:dbghelp:elf_search_auxv can't find symbol in module
0094:fixme:dbghelp:elf_search_auxv can't find symbol in module
0094:fixme:dbghelp:elf_search_auxv can't find symbol in module
0094:fixme:dbghelp:elf_search_auxv can't find symbol in module
0094:fixme:dbghelp:elf_search_auxv can't find symbol in module
0094:fixme:dbghelp:elf_search_auxv can't find symbol in module
0094:fixme:dbghelp:elf_search_auxv can't find symbol in module
0094:fixme:dbghelp:elf_search_auxv can't find symbol in module
0094:fixme:dbghelp:elf_search_auxv can't find symbol in module
0094:fixme:dbghelp:elf_search_auxv can't find symbol in module
003c:err:service:process_send_command service protocol error - failed to read pipe r = 0  count = 0!
003c:fixme:service:scmdatabase_autostart_services Auto-start service L"winebus" failed to start: 1053
wine: failed to open "/Desktop/Multiecuscan.lnk": c0000135```.

I use Kubuntu 22.04 LTS btw
````

Comment: **Welcome to the Ask Ubuntu community.** Your question as written is unclear. Have you successfully run other Windows applications via Wine, or does just this one application fail? Did this application used to run and now doesn't, or has it always generated this error? While you may find some support here, you might be better served working with the [Wine support community](https://www.winehq.org/help), as this issue as described seems more related to running this particular application under Wine than it does with an issue with the Ubuntu OS. Edits to clarify the issue would be helpful.